# Swagger migration from 1.2 to 2.0 specification

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I have Swagger 1.2 JSON spec which I wanted to migrate to Swagger 2.0. Can someone help with that?

Answer (score 13):

You can use [api-spec-converter](https://github.com/lucybot/api-spec-converter) (open-source, MIT license).

```
api-spec-converter https://api.gettyimages.com/swagger/api-docs --from=swagger_1 --to=swagger_2 > swagger.json
```

Comment: To the future: the path you enter should return something like `{"apiVersion":"1.0.0","swaggerVersion":"1.2","apis":[{"path":"/foo"}],...`

Comment: I've tried to convert with api-spec-converter --from=swagger_1 --to=swagger_2 --syntax=yaml --check  --dummy input.yaml > swagger.yaml but I get a Type error . My Yaml version is 1.2. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Is there any possibility to check if existing swagger version 1.2 is a valid one ?

Answer (score 1):

The official swagger codegen allows for this as well:

https://generator.swagger.io/#!/clients/generateClient

Select `swagger-yaml` from the drop-down and put the URL into the `GeneratorInput` example.  It will give you a link to download the swagger definition.

Comment: No longer available.

Comment: I guess it's the `/gen/clients/{language}` endpoint from the [Generator API](https://generator.swagger.io). You can get more infos in the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen).